# Need some help in Java Inheritance! (In LuxuryCarRental int days is always coming as 0)

Tags: java, inheritance

Create a class named CarRental that contains fields that hold a renter’s name, zip code, size of the car rented, daily rental fee, length of rental in days, and total rental fee. The class contains a constructor that requires all the rental data accept the daily rate and total fee, which are calculated, based on the size of the car: economy at $29.99 per day, midsize at $38.99 per day, or full size at $43.50 per day. The class also includes a display() method that displays all the rental data.

Create a subclass named LuxuryCarRental. This class sets the rental fee at $79.99 per day and prompts the user to respond to the option of including a chauffeur at $200 more per day. Override the parent class display() method to include chauffeur fee information. Write an application named UseCarRental that prompts the user for the data needed for a rental and creates an object of the correct type. Display the total rental fee.

Save the files as CarRental. java, LuxuryCarRental. java, and UseCarRental. java

```
public class CarRental
{
String name;
int zip;
String size;
double dailyFee;
int days;
double total;

public CarRental(String size)
{

if(size.charAt(0)=='e')
  dailyFee = 29.99;
else if(size.charAt(0)=='m')
  dailyFee = 38.99;
else
  dailyFee =43.50;
}
public String getname()
{
  return name;
}
public int getzip()
{
  return zip;
}
public String getsize()
{
return size;
}
public int getdays()
{
  return days;
}
public void computetotal(int days)
{
total = dailyFee*days;
}
public void print()
{
System.out.println("The cost of your rental car is $" + total);
}
} 






public class LuxuryCarRental extends CarRental
{
public LuxuryCarRental(String size, int days)
{
super(size);
}
public void computetotal1()
{
super.computetotal(days);
dailyFee = 79.99;
 total = dailyFee;
System.out.println(days);    //trying to see if days still 0
}
}






import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class UseCarRental
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
int days;
String name;
int zip;
String size;
Scanner inputDevice = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter days: ");
days= inputDevice.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter name: ");
name = inputDevice.next();
System.out.println("Enter zip: ");
zip = inputDevice.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter size: ");
size = inputDevice.next();
CarRental econ = new CarRental(size);
econ.computetotal(days);
econ.print();
CarPhone full = new CarPhone(size, days);
full.computetotal1();
full.print();
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not doing anything with days in LuxuryCarRental, your constructor takes it as an argument but does nothing with it. Ideally it should be passed to the CarRental object constructor but in any case, add

```
this.days = days;
```

to LuxuryCarRental constructor, or better your CarRental constructor with a new argument.

There is no need to rename your computetotal method either,leave it with the same name; it the child object will override the implementation details from its parent. Look in to polymorphism: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming

Also, indent your code to make it more readable http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style

Comment: Thank you very much Guys!!! Now I got it! There were lots of things to do I know, but now I got the days (inherited) so I can complete the work!! AGAIN THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

You're not initializing days anywhere in both the classes, that's why getdays is returning 0. Please initialize days, before accessing it.

In constructor of CarRental class, make days as an argument, like this:

```
public CarRental(String size, int days)
{

   if(size.charAt(0)=='e')
      dailyFee = 29.99;
   else if(size.charAt(0)=='m')
      dailyFee = 38.99;
   else
      dailyFee =43.50;
   this.days = days;
}
```

In LuxuryCarRental's constructor, do this:

```
public LuxuryCarRental(String size, int days)
{
   super(size, days);
}
```